# How to compress and clean logs with logrotate but not rotate them

Tags: tomcat, logrotate

I have a Tomcat server which create access logs via  a valve ([org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve)). This valve takes care of rotating the access log file, but not of compressing them or deleting them after some time.

For the moment, I have a cron job that uses `find [...] -mtime +30 [...]` to compress and delete the logs. I would rather use logrotate, so that log rotation is in a centralized place for all logs. I dont like having a seperate solution just for Tomcat.

I tried to read logrotate documentation, but I am still a bit lost. Can I use logrotate just to compress and cleanup log files ? How would I do that ?

Or turning the problem around, is there a Tomcat access log valve that will compress and cleanup log files ?

Thank for your help !

Comment: BTW: FastCommonAccessLogValve is deprecated in 6.0 http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/FastCommonAccessLogValve.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fairly simple one that i have seen works like this.

Create a file in /etc/logrotate.d called tomcat containing the following:-

```
/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out { 
  copytruncate 
  daily 
  rotate 7 
  compress 
  missingok 
}
```

This runs *daily*, *compress*es the file, and keeps 7 days worth (*rotate 7*). *copytruncate* means that it'll copy then truncate the original file so that there is no need to restart tomcat. *missing ok* will not error if it's not there.

The access.log Valve can be changed to not rotate by adding rotatable=false:-

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve
     ...
     ...
     suffix="log" rotatable="false" />
```

Comment: My problem is that unlike catalina.out, my access log is already rotated.

Comment: Okay, access log rotation can be disabled by setting rotatable=false in the Valve arguments. Answeraltered to include this.

Answer (score 2):

Modified TimP's script--Added deleting very old files,  added scan for old compressed files.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# TPP 2013-02-21
# RJK 2014-08-14
#
# Tomcat apps use a variety of loggers, mostly log4j.
# These rotate, conflicting with logrotate, the unix log rotation system.
#
# Some files eg catalina.out
# are rotated to a backup containing a date eg catalina.2013-01-06.log
# which can then be compressed with bz2 to catalina.2013-01-06.log.bz2
# or removed if older than a given number of days(MTIME).
#
cd /var/log/tomcat6
# 2013-02-21
DATE=`date --rfc-3339=date`
YEAR=`date +%Y`
MILLENIUM=20
# 2014-08-14
MTIME=14
# 2014-08-14
#for f in $(find catalina* |grep -v bz2 |grep -v '$DATE' |grep $YEAR)
for f in $(find catalina* |grep -v bz2 |grep -v '$DATE' |grep $MILLENIUM)
do
 # 2014-08-14
 if test `find $f -mtime +$MTIME`
 then
   echo "rm -f $f"
   rm -f $f
 else
   echo "bzip2 $f"
   bzip2 $f
 fi
done
# However others are active whilst containing a date
# so we will find all and not compress the most recent
for l in 'localhost*' 'opt-db*' 'opt*' 'host-manager*' 'manager*'
do
 export previous=
 for f in $(find $l |grep -v bz2 |sort)
 do
  if [ "${previous}" != "" ]
  then
    echo "bzip2 ${previous}"
    bzip2 $previous
  fi
  export previous=$f
 done
done
# 2014-08-14
for f in $(find *bz2)
do
 if test `find $f -mtime +$MTIME`
 then
   echo "rm -f $f"
   rm -f $f
 fi
done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It's surprisingly simple.  Just tell logrotate which files you specifically want to rotate.  `nocreate` tells logrotate not to recreate an empty file after moving the old one (if you're rotating files into a subfolder).

```
/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out.* { 
  daily 
  nocreate
  compress 
  missingok 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not wish to change the Tomcat configuration, 
so created a script which compressed the rotated files

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# TPP 2013-02-21
#
# Tomcat apps use a variety of loggers, mostly log4j.
# These rotate, conflicting with logrotate, the unix log rotation system. 
#
# Some files eg catalina.out
# are rotated to a backup containing a date eg catalina.2013-01-06.log
# which can then be compressed with bz2 to catalina.2013-01-06.log.bz2
#

cd /var/log/tomcat6

# 2013-02-21
DATE=`date --rfc-3339=date`
YEAR=`date +%Y`

for f in $(find catalina* |grep -v bz2 |grep -v '$DATE' |grep $YEAR)
do
 echo "bzip2 $f" 
 bzip2 $f
done

# However others are active whilst containing a date
# so we will find all and not compress the most recent
for l in 'localhost*' 'opt-db*' 'opt*' 'host-manager*' 'manager*'
do
 export previous=
 for f in $(find $l |grep -v bz2 |sort)
 do
  if [ "${previous}" != "" ]
  then
    echo "bzip2 ${previous}" 
    bzip2 $previous
  fi
  export previous=$f
 done
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For local_access_log.YYYY-MM-DD.txt compression I wrote this script after seeing this post :-

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# If Tomcat uses server.xml config to rotate localhost_access_log,
# the daily rotated logs will need compressing and old ones deleted to stop filling
# the log partiton. Cannot use the system logrotate command as conficts with tomcat rotate
# therefore run this script in a daily cronjob
#
# localhost_access_log.2015-09-03.txt
#
# Add this script in /etc/cron.daily/ owned by root
#

CATALINA_BASE=`ps aux | grep catalina.base | awk -F'catalina.base\=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`

if [ ! $CATALINA_BASE ]
then
    if [ -r /var/lib/tomcat8 ]
    then
        CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat8
    else
        echo "Error: cannot find CATALINA_BASE"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

cd ${CATALINA_BASE}/logs

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Error, cannot cd to logs directory, quitting...."
    exit 1
fi

# today's date (not to be gzipped)
DATE=`date --rfc-3339=date`
# number of days to keep
MTIME=28

# Compress all previous days uncompressed logs
for log in `ls localhost_access_log* | grep -v bz2 | grep -v $DATE`
do
    bzip2 $log
done

# delete old logs
find . -name "*.bz2" -mtime +$MTIME -exec rm {} \;

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution provided here. This also includes the s3 upload option.

https://yottabrain.org/tomcat/tomcat-log-backup/

Comment: domain is gone ... Wayback:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170410025123/http://www.techiewiki.org/wiki/Tomcat_log_backup